# What Are The Most Popular jQuery Plugin Patterns?

Tags: jquery, plugins, design-patterns

I'm writing an open-source mini-book on jQuery Plugin Development Patterns and am interested in hearing what you guys feel are the most popular plugin patterns at the moment. (If you could provide an example too when answering that would be a big plus)

There are at least 4 unique ones which I've identified so far, including DRY, but what others do you think are important for developers to consider?

My aim is to give people a solid set of examples and reasons why one may be more favorable than another for particular situations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might need to be set as a community wiki as there may not be a "best" answer. Also it would help if you told us which 4 patterns you identified.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this [Starter](http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/) as my base plugin template by Doug Neiner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that resource. I know Doug and wasn't aware that a tool like this existed. Will provide at least a good reference point :)

Comment: Oh cool... actually I think he's already posted about it as well: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-plugin-design-patterns-part-i/